# Does anyone know why i do not get an output, the code does compile but returns no output

Tags: python, list, set

```
employees =[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "job": "Software Engineer",
        "City": "Vancouver",
        "age": 34,
        "status": "single"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alicia Smith",
        "job": "Director",
        "City": "New York",
        "age": 38,
        "status": "Married"
    }
] 

keys = ["name", "age"]


if "name" and "age" in employees:
 newDict = employees.pop("name" and "age")
 print(newDict)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Please give your expected output

Comment: your if statement doesn't do what you think it does. It's currently doing (name) and (age in employees)

Comment: Explaining what you are trying to do and what output in particular you want is good practice in general. If you haven't already, check out this link describing [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code. I believe that you're trying to remove the keys `name` and `age` from the dictionaries wherever present. Try the following:

```py
employees = [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "job": "Software Engineer",
        "City": "Vancouver",
        "age": 34,
        "status": "single"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alicia Smith",
        "job": "Director",
        "City": "New York",
        "age": 38,
        "status": "Married"
    }
]

newDict = []
for d in employees:   # First iterate over the dictionaries
    if "name" in d:   # If the key "name" is there in the dictionary
        d.pop("name") # Remove it
    if "age" in d:    # Check if "age" is there in the keys
        d.pop("age")  # Remove it too if present
    newDict.append(d) # Add the updated dictionary to our list
print(newDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) inside a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for a one-liner.

```py
print([{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in keys} for d in employees])
```

If you want to perform it in multiple lines, you should make a copy of the dictionary before removing items from it. Otherwise, you would get the following error.

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score -2):

first you got two errors in the code the first one because the if statement is not correct that is why is not being executed. second you can't pop a dict inside array you got to choose each one and then pop them or put them in loop like this solution

```
employees =[ { "name": "John Doe", "job": "Software Engineer", "City": "Vancouver", "age": 34, "status": "single" }, { "name": "Alicia Smith", "job": "Director", "City": "New York", "age": 38, "status": "Married" } ]
newDict = []
for i in employees:
    if "name" and "age" in i:
        i.pop("name" and "age")
        newDict.append(i)
print(newDict)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).